# Jackson Mixing not working

Tags: json, jackson, mixins, fasterxml

Here is a 3rd party class (Let's assume for example sake)

```
public class User {
private Integer userId;
private String password;

public User(Integer userId, String password) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.password = password;
}

public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [userId=" + userId + ", password=" + password + "]";
}
}
```

Here is the corresponding mixing class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public abstract class UserMixin {

@JsonProperty("userId")
abstract String getUserId();

@JsonProperty("password")
abstract String getPassword();

@JsonCreator
public UserMixin(
        @JsonProperty("userId") Integer userId
        , @JsonProperty("password") String password) {
    System.out.println("mixed-in constructor.");
}
}
```

Here is the corresponding Driver class

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonMixIn {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    User user = new User(1,  "password");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
    System.out.println(json);

    ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper2.addMixIn(User.class, UserMixin.class);

    System.out.println(mapper2.writeValueAsString(user));

    final User deserializedUser = mapper2.readValue(json, User.class);
    System.out.println(deserializedUser);
}
}
```

If I run the driver class every thing works like a charm, and getting the output as expected.

```
{"userId":1,"password":"password"}
{"userId":1,"password":"password"}
User [userId=1, password=password]
```

However If I remove the the following getters of User class

```
public Integer getUserId() {
   return userId;
}

public String getPassword() {
   return password;
}
```

I am getting the following exception

**Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.github.dexecutor.redisson.User and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:269)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:32)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3631)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2998)
    at com.github.dexecutor.redisson.JacksonMixIn.main(JacksonMixIn.java:13)**

Comment: I think, it is what it is, the framework is not that intelligent enough (or designed) to work with this cases
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1380#issuecomment-248753018

Comment: I have added the answer [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1380)

Comment: I have documented about this behaviour [here](https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2016/09/23/jackson-mixin-to-the-rescue/)

Answer (score 0):

All that should done is the following and things should work like a charm

```
mapper.setVisibility(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
        .getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

Refer [this](https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2016/09/23/jackson-mixin-to-the-rescue/) for more details